# Confused on Different Android Storage Locations

Tags: android, storage, external, internal

**What I Have**

I just have a simple application in which the user will select a file, my app will proccess it and place it in the same place but on the topmost (or root) directory.

**The Problem**

I want to make it generalized. he user may select the file from:

i) Internal Storage
ii) External SD Card
iii) Any USB OTG
iv) Or in case of multi-user storage (like storage/emulated/0)

For example, the user selects a file from the USB OTG (storage/sdcard1/Pics/123.jpg), I want to process the file and place it in (storage/sdcard1/123.jpg), that is the topmost location of any storage.

**The Confusion**

There are a variety of such storage locations and they are even different for different Android devices. In some we have storage/sdcard0 and in some we have storage/sdcard/emulated/0

I am really confused with this and want a generalized solution to get the topmost or the root directory of any such location?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you junk up the root directory of any file storage system with user files? The reason we have structured file systems is to separate different types of file (system files, data files, user files etc etc).

Comment: I want to create a folder specific to my app in the root folder and then put files there. I intend to keep things organized. It would be great if you can provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: I agree with @Squonk . People using Windows on computers tend to place files in random places, also, lots of Windows software installs itself in semi-random places, for example, one application installs itself in `Program Files/AppName`, other one - in `C://CompanyName/AppName`. Some applications download data not to `Downloads` folder, but somewhere in `appname/downloads`. In Unix, structure has to be followed - user's applications go to `bin`, either in `/` or `~`, depending on who should use it.

Comment: Did you understand my problem? I need to place a file which is suppose in an USB OTG to that place only. I cannot process it and then place it in the device.

Comment: So, I think you're trying to make it easier for the user to find the data files being processed. I think that's probably a pretty good idea.  Whenever I use an app that tells me go to "a/b/c/d/foo.bar" to get the data you just exported I die a little.

Comment: @TomHennen Yes, it is. Any solution to the problem?

Comment: I don't have one. Hopefully someone else will.